# Autofac: Trying to prevent memory leak using child lifetime

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, autofac

As many others it seems googling the topic, I am causing memory leaks by resolving instances because the instances are saved in autofac lists of disposable references.

I know the "easy way out" is to register them as `ExternallyOwned`, but I don't really like that. It feels like a bit of a hack, and it becomes my responsibility to dispose them.

I thought I would be able to solve the problem by creating child lifetimes as follow

```
    private async void TimerOnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await using var childLifetime = _lifetime.BeginLifetimeScope();
        try
        {
            using var userRepository = childLifetime.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
            // ...
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // ...
        }
        finally
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

But when running the application, I still observe that instances of `IUserRepository` created in this timer callback, are never finalized.

I also tried to overwrite the registration with `ExternallyOwned`

```
    await using var childLifetime = _lifetime.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().ExternallyOwned();
    });
```

But this doesn't change anything.

Am I misunderstanding autofac's child lifetimes? Shouldn't the child lifetime keep track of the disposable instances resolved from that child lifetime? And shouldn't that child lifetime be finalized when it runs out of scope of the timer callback?

If somebody has a suggestion how to achieve the same without using externally owned in the root container registrations, I'm all ears.

Comment: Not enough here to reproduce. What dependencies does user repo have? Is it disposable? How is it (and dependencies) registered? Need minimum reproducible example.

Comment: @TravisIllig could I bother you to have a look at below solution. It works nice for me, especially allowing me to unit test the classes that are composing stuff using AutoMock from Autofac.Extras. Would love to hear your opinion on my approach (also if it's negative :))

Answer (score 0):

Travis pointed out the actual problem in his comment. The dependencies tree eventually killed me, forcing me to register more types as `ExternallyOwned` which feels "wrong".

I found a solution I prefer over gradually registering more and more types as `ExternallyOwned`.

Some context, I am written "yet another web app" where I heavily rely on autofac. My web app mostly responds to API calls. For each web api call MVC instantiates a new `Controller`, and autofac injects the dependencies. All goes well.

But, I also have a couple of background services, which rely on a timer to elapse. These timers are instantiated at app startup, and live throughout the lifetime of my app.

These do get problematic, because every time the timer elapses, I resolve objects from the root container through `Func` factories. Every time this happens, a new instance is added to the list of disposable instances maintained by the lifetime scope. Overtime, this will make the app run out of memory since this lifetime scope lives throughout the lifetime of the web app as well.

The "quick fix" was, to just mark the types I resolved as `ExternallyOwned`, but I really hate that design. When I add dependencies to any class, I need to check if that dependency also roots back to one of my background services and mark the registration as `ExternallyOwned` if that happened to be the case.

So the "simplest" solution I came up with, is to wrap the autofac's ILifetimeScope and allow that wrapper to register a generic module.

```
public class DedicatedLifetimeScope<T> : IDedicatedLifetimeScope where T : Module, new()
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public DedicatedLifetimeScope(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
    {
        return _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule<T>();
        });
    }
}
```

I registered this type as following:

```
builder.RegisterType<DedicatedLifetimeScope<ApplicationModule>>().As<IDedicatedLifetimeScope>();
```

Where my `ApplicationModule` represents my root container.

This basically overwrites all registrations in a child lifetime, ensuring that everything that is resolved from my background services is retrieved from my child lifetime.

An example "background service"

```
public class CheckOpenInvoicesTimer
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CheckOpenInvoicesTimer));
    
    private readonly ISystemTimer _timer;
    private readonly ITimerSettings _timerSettings;
    private readonly IDedicatedLifetimeScope _dedicatedLifetimeScope;

    public CheckOpenInvoicesTimer(
        ISystemTimer timer, 
        ITimerSettings timerSettings,
        IDedicatedLifetimeScope dedicatedLifetimeScope)
    {
        _timer = timer;
        _timerSettings = timerSettings;
        _dedicatedLifetimeScope = dedicatedLifetimeScope;

        _timer.Interval = _timerSettings.ReadOpenInvoicesTimer();
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.TimerElapsed += TimerOnTimerElapsed;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private async void TimerOnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var lifetime = _dedicatedLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();
            using var userRepository = lifetime.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
            
            foreach (var userEntity in userRepository.FindAll())
            {
                var openInvoicesService = lifetime.Resolve<IOpenInvoicesService>();
                await openInvoicesService.ReportOutstandingOpenInvoices(userEntity.UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error("An exception occurred while sending invoices", exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            _timer.Interval = _timerSettings.ReadOpenInvoicesTimer();
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering why autofac wouldn't track disposable instances in the child lifetime scopes anyway. Then I would be able to just create a child lifetime scope without registering anything at all. I am sure there are good arguments against that approach :).

If anybody would have information on why autofac choose to track disposables in the lifetime scope where the registration was done initially, or if anybody have would have arguments why my handrolled solution is a recipe for disaster on the long run; I am eager to learn why, and hopefully what would be a better solution.